# Add custom class to @Html.DropDownListFor Asp.net Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add custom class to Asp.net Razor MVC control `@Html.DropDownListFor`

I have following code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.is_admin, new SelectList(
            new List<Object>{ 
                new { value = "true" , text = "Admin"  },  
                new { value = "false" , text = "User"  },                                               
             },                    
             "value",
             "text",
              "false" ))
```

How can this same control be implemented in Asp.net MVC 5

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.is_admin, new SelectList(....), new { @class = "yourClassName" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a third parameter called `htmlAttributes` like following.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.is_admin,
       new SelectList(
           new List<Object>{
               new { value = "true" , text = "Admin"  },
               new { value = "false" , text = "User"  },

            }, "value", "text", "false"),
       new { @class = "your_class_name" });
```